# How to use nn.MultiheadAttention together with nn.LSTM?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

I'm trying to build a Pytorch network for image captioning.
Currently I have a working network of Encoder and Decoder, and I want to add `nn.MultiheadAttnetion` layer to it (to be used as self attention).

Currently my decode looks like this:

```py
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, embed_dim, vocab_size, layers = 1):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()

        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.layers = layers
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim, padding_idx=0)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size = embed_dim, hidden_size = hidden_size, batch_first = True, num_layers = layers)
        #self.attention = nn.MultiheadAttention(hidden_size, num_heads=1, batch_first= True)


        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, self.vocab_size)

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        h = torch.zeros(self.layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c = torch.zeros(self.layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        return h,c

    def forward(self, features, caption):
        batch_size = caption.size(0)
        caption_size = caption.size(1)
        
        h,c = self.init_hidden(batch_size)
                
        embeddings = self.embedding(caption)  

        lstm_input = torch.cat((features.unsqueeze(1), embeddings[:,:-1,:]), dim=1)
        output, (h,c) = self.lstm(lstm_input, (h,c))
        
        #output, _ = self.attention(output, output, output)
        
        output = self.fc(output)

        return output   
    
    def generate_caption(self, features, max_caption_size = MAX_LEN):
        h,c = self.init_hidden(1)
        
        caption = ""
        embeddings = features.unsqueeze(1)

        for i in range(max_caption_size):
            output, (h, c) = self.lstm(embeddings, (h,c))
            #output, _ = self.attention(output, output, output)
            output = self.fc(output)
            _, word_index = torch.max(output, dim=2) # take the word with highest probability
            if word_index == vocab.get_index(END_WORD):
                break
            caption += vocab.get_word(word_index) + " "
            embeddings = self.embedding(torch.LongTensor([word_index]).view(1,-1).to(device))
            
        return caption
```

and it gives relatively good results for image captioning.
I want to add the commented out lines so the model will use Attention. But- when I do that- the model breaks, although the loss becomes extremely low (decreasing from 2.7 to 0.2 during training instead of 2.7 to 1 without the attention) - the caption generation is not really working (predicts the same word over and over again).

My questions are:

1. Am I using the `nn.MultiheadAttention` correctly? it is very weird to me that it should be used **after** the LSTM, but I saw this online, and it works from dimension sizes perspective
2. Any idea why my model breaks when I use Attention?

**EDIT**: I also tried to put the Attention **before** the LSTM, and it didn't work as well (network predicted the same caption for every picture)